# Consultar imagem em uma pasta

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um programa em windows form e nesse programa gostaria de selecionar uma opção no combobox e ele carregar a imagem na picturebox. Está imagem vai ter o nome que foi selecionado na combobox.

EX: combobox= banana
ele vai na pasta que estão as fotos e procura a que esta com o nome banana e carrega ela na picture box.

Podem me ajudar?

codigo usado para salvar imagem na pasta:

```
 pictureBox6.Image.Save(@"E:\Programas\Projetos\Imagen\" + textBox1.Text + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Sim, podemos ajudar. Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como realizar esse procedimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber sempre que o usuário selecionar um valor no combobox será necessário usar o evento **`SelectedIndexChanged`** (ou qualquer um similar).

Para carregar um `PictureBox` com uma imagem do sistema de arquivos, você pode usar [**`Image.FromFile(string caminhoImagem)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

Código de exemplo abaixo. Obviamente levando em consideração que os itens do *combobox* sejam *strings* e que o texto do combo contenha a extensão da imagem.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    string imgSelecionada = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;

    CarregarImagem(imgSelecionada);
}

private void CarregarImagem(string nomeImagem)
{
    const string pastaRaiz = @"E:\Programas\Projetos\Imagen"; 

    var caminhoImagem = Path.Combine(pastaRaiz, nomeImagem);    

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(caminhoImagem);    
}
```